# Testing List of Lists to remove unwanted lists based on a constraint

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a list of lists. The lists are made up of people from certain areas, if the lists have too many people from a certain area I would like to remove the list from the set of lists. The lists are lengths of 9

```
list=[[["Aarat","California"],
["Aaron","California"],
["Abba","California"],
["Abaddon","California"],
["Abner","Nevada"],
["Abram","Nevada"],
["Abraham","Nevada"],
["Absalom","Nevada"],
["Adullam","Utah"]],
......,
[["Abital","California"],
["Abitub","California"],
["Absalom","Nevada"],
["Accad","Nevada"],
["Agar","Utah"],
["Agee","Utah"],
["Aijeleth-Shahar","New Mexico"],
["Ain","New Mexico"],
["Amram","Washington"]]]
Cities=["California","Nevada","Utah","New Mexico","Idaho","Washington"]
denk=[] 
for city in Cities:
    den=[]
    for i in list:
        a=i[0]
        b=i[1]
        c=i[2]
        d=i[3]
        e=i[4]
        f=i[5]
        g=i[6]
        h=i[7]
        k=i[8]
        if a==city:
            ab=1
        if b==city:
            ac=1
        if c==city:
            ad=1
        if d==city:
            ae=1
        if e==city:
            af=1
        if f==city:
            ag=1
        if g==city:
            ah=1
        if h==city:
            ai=1
        if k==city:
            aj=1
        if (ab+ac+ad+ae+af+ag+ah+ai+aj)>3:
            den.append(1)
        if (ab+ac+ad+ae+af+ag+ah+ai+aj)<4:
            den.append(0)
    denk.append(sum(den))

finalList=[]
for i, j in enumerate(denk):
    if j == 0:
        finalList.append(list[i])
```

I attempt to count the amount of people from the city, if the amount of people is greater than 3 I try to append a 1, if not 0. I only do this so i can sum up the amount of times the list goes over the quota.

```
Cities=["California","Nevada","Utah","New Mexico","Idaho","Washington"]

[["Aarat","California"],
["Aaron","California"],
["Abba","California"],
["Abaddon","California"],
["Abner","Nevada"],
["Abram","Nevada"],
["Abraham","Nevada"],
["Absalom","Nevada"],
["Adullam","Utah"]]
```

In testing this particular list the testing to see how many people are from California would make den=1 because there are more than 3 people from California. The next city, Nevada, would also make den=1, and so on....
den=[1,1,0,0,0,0]
denk=[2]
So this list gets thrown out

```
[["Abital","California"],
["Abitub","California"],
["Absalom","Nevada"],
["Accad","Nevada"],
["Agar","Utah"],
["Agee","Utah"],
["Aijeleth-Shahar","New Mexico"],
["Ain","New Mexico"],
["Amram","Washington"]]
```

Doing the same here yields den=0 for each city in Cities, den=[0,0,0,0,0,0], denk=[0] so the list will be accepted.

The finalList should not have any lists that have too many people from one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you start with something like:

```
list=[[["Aarat","California"],
    ["Aaron","California"],
    ["Abba","California"],
    ["Abaddon","California"],
    ["Abner","Nevada"],
    ["Abram","Nevada"],
    ["Abraham","Nevada"],
    ["Absalom","Nevada"],
    ["Adullam","Utah"]],[["Abital","California"],
    ["Abitub","California"],
    ["Absalom","Nevada"],
    ["Accad","Nevada"],
    ["Agar","Utah"],
    ["Agee","Utah"],
    ["Aijeleth-Shahar","New Mexico"],
    ["Ain","New Mexico"],
    ["Amram","Washington"]]]
```

To find the distribution within each second-level list, you could use list comprehension and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

>>> [collections.Counter(e[1] for e in l) for l in list]
[Counter({'California': 4, 'Nevada': 4, 'Utah': 1}),
 Counter({'California': 2,
          'Nevada': 2,
          'New Mexico': 2,
          'Utah': 2,
          'Washington': 1})]
```

To find the most common count within each second-level list, you could use

```
>>> [collections.Counter(e[1] for e in l).most_common(1)[0][1] for l in list]
[4, 2]
```

So, to retain only second-level lists where the most common count is at most, say, 3, you could just use

```
>>> [l for l in list if collections.Counter(e[1] for e in l).most_common(1)[0][1] <= 3]
[[['Abital', 'California'],
  ['Abitub', 'California'],
  ['Absalom', 'Nevada'],
  ['Accad', 'Nevada'],
  ['Agar', 'Utah'],
  ['Agee', 'Utah'],
  ['Aijeleth-Shahar', 'New Mexico'],
  ['Ain', 'New Mexico'],
  ['Amram', 'Washington']]]
```

Comment: what does the last code return? if i print list it seems to return the same as before.

Comment: This doesn't modify `list` - it returns a new list. If you want to modify `list`, write `list = [l for l in list if...`.